# Cannot read property 'path' of undefined while uploading image upload on the frontend(react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am trying to upload an image on the frontend, but this is not working, I am getting the error below

```
message: "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"
status: "fail"
```

When I log req.file on the backend and try to upload on the frontend, I get undefined in the console, but this gets logged for req.body

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  name: 'sfdgg',
  description: 'dsfdgg',
  reviewImage: '[object Object]' }
```

Image upload works fine on the backend via Postman.

Here is the frontend logic

```js
const formData = new FormData();

for (let key in review) {
  formData.append(key, review[key]);
}

formData.append("reviewImage", reviewImage)

console.log(reviewImage)

axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/reviews", formData,{
    headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/formdata"
    }
})
```

Removing the content-type doesn't work, as it does not work with the content-type as well.

Multer config

```js
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

upload.single("reviewImage");
```

Seen similar questions, but the answers do not work for me, kindly assist.

Comment: Where is the error actually occurring?

Comment: The issue may due to the reviewImage object in request parameter missing the key path.

Comment: the error is occurring on the frontend @Jayce444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for adding file in form data

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#reviewImage');
formData.append("reviewImage", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/reviews", formData, {
    headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/formdata"
    }
})
```